# Twitter API v2.0 DELETE request using httr and R

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, httr

With little experience in API programming, I am looking for a way to send a [DELETE](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/api-reference/delete-users-source_id-following) or [POST](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/api-reference/post-users-source_user_id-following) request using the Twitter API v2.0 with the httr package in R. I usually use the [academictwitteR](https://github.com/cjbarrie/academictwitteR) package to interact with the API, but the package uses a bearer token authentication that seems to me to not be adequate for write privileges (required by DELETE and POST). Therefore, it seemed that the first step is setting up the OAuth 1.0a authentication credintials as [described here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a). I downloaded and stored the four variables (`oauth_token`; `oauth_token_secret`; `oauth_consumer_key`; `oauth_consumer_secret`) from the app I created, but then I am stuck as to how to set up the request with `httr`.

I can't provide an example since I could not figure out the code, I hope you understand. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your specific requirements and what you tried before.

Would it be a solution to just use the `rtweet` package?

It is quite handy and offers quite a lot of functions to interact with the twitter api(also posting and deleting tweets possible)

E.g.

```
#Posting
post_tweet("hello world")

#Following
post_follow("someuser")

# Not sure about deleting, but should work like this
post_tweet(destroy_id= "postID")
```

To get you post ID to delete it, you can get maybe use `get_my_timeline`. This should give your posts with ids.

See here in the vignette for a short [intro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/intro.html) about functions.

Of course you also need an access token first.
They have a very good [explanation page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/auth.html) on how to do this. Also a [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/FAQ.html) for problems. The explanation is rather long and probably too specific to go through in  detail here. But would be interesting to know if it works for you.

Further things:

1. Make sure you have httpuv installed
2. Be sure to have the very latest rtweet version (best is from github I think)
3. Also check the following: Go to developer.twitter.com/en/apps and then to your app. Under 'Permissions' make sure to give Read and Write. Under 'App Detail' add 127.0.0.1:1410 as Callback Url. Under 'Keys and tokens' create your Keys
4. Regenerate your tokens/keys

So try this:

```
install.packages("httpuv")
devtools::install_github("mkearney/rtweet")

library(rtweet)
library(httpuv)

create_token(
app = appname,
consumer_key = key,
consumer_secret = secret,
access_token = access_token,
access_secret = access_secret
)
```

**Update**
I just saw, on the very latest version in github they completely changed their methods and `create_token` is now depreciated.

Here is the new way to do it: [documentation](https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/reference/rtweet_user.html)

So seems you habe to use `rtweet_bot()` now.

```
library("askpass")
rtweet_bot(
  api_key = askpass("API key"),
  api_secret = askpass("API secret"),
  access_token = askpass("access token"),
  access_secret = askpass("access token")
)
```

The rest of the code I posted should stay the same.

In general it seems there are 3 ways of authenticating now:

> rtweet_user() interactively authenticates an existing twitter user.
> This form is most appropriate if you want rtweet to control your
> twitter account.
>
> rtweet_app() authenticates as a twitter application. An application
> can't perform actions (i.e. it can't tweet) but otherwise has
> generally higher rate limits (i.e. you can do more searches). See
> details at
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits.html. This
> form is most appropriate if you are collecting data.
>
> rtweet_bot() authenticates as bot that takes actions on behalf of an
> app. This form is most appropriate if you want to create a twitter
> account that is run by a computer, rather than a human.

Comment: I know the package, but as I mentioned in the question I have an issue with the oauth process. I tried

 token <- create_token(app=app, 
             consumer_key = oauth_consumer_key,
             consumer_secret = oauth_consumer_secret,
             access_token=oauth_token,
             access_secret=oauth_consumer_secret)

get_token()

I also added the callback URLs in the app to  https://127.0.0.1:1410/, and to http://127.0.0.1:1410/, but nothing happens in the browser after get_token(), except an output in the R console. I think the API has changed after the package release

Comment: Did you also try the "1. Browser-based authentication" from the explanation page?

Comment: Just to be sure, I'll try the authentication myself later. But I am pretty sure it should work. The package has 25k downloads per month and I see no recent issue (https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues) that authentication does not work any more. Can you post the console output?

Comment: Also check the following: Go to https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps/ and then to your app. Under 'Permissions' make sure to give Read and Write. Under 'App Detail' add http://127.0.0.1:1410 as Callback Url. Under 'Keys and tokens' create your Keys.

Comment: So, if I do the first method 1. Browser-based authentication I get this error: Error in twitter_init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  : 
  Forbidden (HTTP 403). If I do the second 2. Access token/secret method, I get this output after get_token() <Token>
<oauth_endpoint>
 request:   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
 authorize: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
 access:    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
<oauth_app> eborbath
  key:    XYZ
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> oauth_token, oauth_token_secret

Comment: I now did not copy the key value, since I did not want to post it here, but it's an alpha numeric string, where I wrote XYZ.

Comment: Added some things to the answer that might help. Especially trying to install the very latest package version from github might help. Try to run the specific code I posted - with your credentials.

Comment: Oh, sorrry further update - in the latest github version the function names have changed.

Comment: I am not sure why, but even after I installed the latest rtweet package (0.7.0.9000) and askpass, it still does not find the ask_pass function. Even if I get it to work, I am also wondering, how to get this to follow/unfollow users that my initial question was, since I could not find a function in rtweet for that - hence I was playing around with httr originally.

Comment: There is a post_follow() method - 'Follows target twitter user.' and there is a post_unfollow_user() function. You can use these :)

Comment: Ok, but does it work for you with the ask_pass function? I am pretty sure I installed the most up do date version with devtools from github, but it still does not find it.

Comment: Oh, you mean because the example uses ask_pass? Seems to be an error, the actual function name is askpass(). You can replace this, or just write "hjd78232" / your key as a string instead.

Comment: The askpass() is only there, that you do not have to type your keys into the console (which is a little bit more secure, when sharing files e.g. on github - because you might e.g. share your .rhistory, where console input is saved).  From their description: "All of the arguments to these functions are roughly equivalent to passwords so should generally not be typed into the console (where they the will be recorded in .Rhistory) or recorded in a script (which is easy to accidentally share). use askpass::askpass() to interactively prompt you for the values."

Comment: Great ! You are welcome, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the curl examples for DELETE and POST requests you provided. They are rewrotten in R below. You need to replace the `$OAUTH_SIGNATURE` though. Please let me know if it works for you as I cannot check the code as I do not have a Twitter account nor do I have the OAuth token.

```
library(httr)

r <- DELETE(url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2244994945/following/6253282",
            add_headers('Authorization'= 'OAuth $OAUTH_SIGNATURE'))

content(r)


r <- POST(
  url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/6253282/following",
  body = c("target_user_id" = "2244994945"),
  add_headers('Authorization'= 'OAuth $OAUTH_SIGNATURE'),
  content_type_json()
  )

content(r)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! How do I get the $OAUTH_SIGNATURE from the four keys though? I found a description here, but I was not sure how to set it up with `httr`:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

Comment: @eborbath I am not familiar with the Twitter API, sorry. Try reading the documentation and identify the http requests you need to do. Please also note you can do curl requests from R if this is a viable option for you.

Comment: Maybe one of these two files could be useful, but as far as I can tell, they authenticate for a shiny app: 1. https://gist.github.com/jnolis/a41c196a5e22e2a2115d28e853d4780c 2. https://gist.github.com/jnolis/49d328f58e6bb0074442d032f4e79c7f

Comment: I tried to google up your problem and there seems to be a package twittR which has a function for setting up OAuth (setup_twitter_oauth("API key", "API secret", "Access token", "Access secret")). Have you considered using that? For me it is very hard to help you as I am not that familiar with OAuth, and without having a chance to test my code, it is hard to come up with something useful.